# Will linked references still work after i change a site to https?

Tags: https

We're looking at changing a site from http to https.

There are some 3rd party sites that hotlink / link to reference images on our site (we have allowed them to do this) but there `<img ref="#">` is to the http content.

Once we move our site to https will the will the linked images still work on their site ?

Their site is http.

Comment: Not that it is your problem, if the remote site is https and they try to load your images over http, they will not get a green padlock as there will be "mixed content" i.e. loading http content over a https connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You will find that:***

- HTTP websites DO NOT have issues with loading HTTPS resources
- HTTPS websites DOES have issues with loading HTTP resources

***Simply ensure you 301 redirect from:***

- FROM:  `http://www.example.com/image.jpg`
- TO: `https://www.example.com/image.jpg`

***Summary***

Sites that do not use SSL will have no issue with your images as long as you have the redirect as previously advised.

Comment: "Sites that do not use SSL will have no issue with your images _as long as you have the redirect as previously advised_." - The redirect will make no difference as to whether the third party site will be able to access the image(s) or not.

Comment: That's correct but you really don't want Google indexing pages or resources on different variations so a redirection is always advisable regardless if it will work without it.